# Is there a command to uninstall?

Tags: unix, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon ec2 Linux instance. I am just wondering if there is a command to uninstall?

For example I used:

> yum install openvpn

How do I do the reverse of this (uninstall)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
yum remove openvpn
```

read

```
man yum
```

for further information.

Answer (score 3):

Use remove:

```
yum remove openvpn
```